# Can a Point Cloud be Spread Through a Smoke Sim?

Tags: particles, smoke-simulation, point-clouds

I'm simulating a sand storm and need a large number of particles in my smoke simulation.

After reading about point clouds in Blender 3.0+ and using a few examples I was wondering whether they could be distributed through a mantaflow smoke sim instead of using particles.  Would they be more efficient?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to drive particles by smoke force ...

- add *Particle System* to *Fluid* object (or any other)
- add *Force Field* object type **[Fluid Flow](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.2/physics/forces/force_fields/types/fluid_flow.html)** and set *Domain Object* under *Physics Properties*.

[image]

- The Empty object in my example is *Force Fields > Turbulence* to make smoke a bit more dramatic :)
- *Gravity* under *Particles Properties* > *Field Wieghts* is almost zero